# How can I serialize only the contents of an object property using System.Text.Json (custom converter or other method)

Tags: c#, json, .net, system.text.json

I am developing a client for an API which expects non conventional json and I cannot find a way produce what it wants using System.Text.Json.

The api in question expects json in the following format:

```json
{
    "user__0__id": XXXX,
    "user__0__email": "XXXX",
    "user__1__id": YYYY,
    "user__1__email": "YYYY"
}
```

I have classes as such:

```
class Request {
   public List<User> Users {get; set;}
}

class User {
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Email {get; set; }
}
```

I have tried using a custom json converter with a write method like this:

```
public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, List<User> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    for (var x = 0; x < value.Count; x++)
    {
        var user = value[x];
        writer.WriteString($"users__{x}__id", user.Id.ToString());
        writer.WriteString($"users__{x}__email", user.Email);
    }
}
```

This kind of works, but the problem is that the serializer will first output the property name ("Users:") and then the rest.

Eg

```json
{
    "Users":"user__0__id":XXXX,
    "user__0__email":"XXXX",
    "user__1__id":YYYY
    "user__1__email":"YYYY"
}
```

Obviously the above doesn't work as it's invalid json.

I've researched docs but couldn't find a way to skip writing the property name and only write the contents of the property, as that's what I need to do basically.

Comment: Can't you just write your own code to serialise it in the required format?

Comment: I could, but while the above are simple examples, the actual object graph is quite big and I would like to avoid it, as it would mean a lot of own code. 

Also, I'm using the Refit library to handle the actual https calls and responses, which uses System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft.Json for serialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate the required JSON from your `Request` class using this `JsonConverter<Request>` rather than a `JsonConverter<List<User>>` as you are currently attempting:

```
class RequestConverter : JsonConverter<Request>
{
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Request value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        for (int x = 0, n = (value.Users == null ? 0 : value.Users.Count); x < n; x++)
        {
            var user = value.Users[x];
            writer.WriteNumber($"users__{x.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)}__id", user.Id);
            writer.WriteString($"users__{x.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)}__email", user.Email);
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }   
    
    public override Request Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

If you prefer to separate the responsibilities for serializing `Request` and `List<User>`, you will need converters for both:

```
class RequestConverter : JsonConverter<Request>
{
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Request value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value.Users, options);
    
    public override Request Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        new Request { Users = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<User>>(ref reader, options) };
}

class UserListConverter : JsonConverter<List<User>>
{
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, List<User> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        for (int x = 0, n = value.Count; x < n; x++)
        {
            var user = value[x];
            writer.WriteNumber($"users__{x.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)}__id", user.Id);
            writer.WriteString($"users__{x.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)}__email", user.Email);
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }   
    
    public override List<User> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Notes:

1. The reason the extra `"Users:"` property shows up is that you created your converter for the inner `List<Users>` property.  Thus `JsonSerializer` will serialize the outer `Request` object using default serialization, then use the converter for the value of `Users`, which results an outer wrapper object like so:

   ```json
   { "Users": /* Value of Users */ }
   ```

   To avoid the wrapper object you need to either serialize `List<User>` directly, or apply the converter to `Request` instead, which is what I do above.
2. In a contract-based serializer such as System.Text.Json (or any other contract-based serializer as far as I know) a child class cannot "reach up" and control the serialization of a parent class. It's the responsibility of each class (or its applicable converter) to define a contract for itself to serialize itself as it sees fit by defining its properties and their value objects, then any child values will get serialized according to their respective contracts.
3. In your converter you need to remember to write the beginning and end object tokens.  If you don't you will write malformed JSON as shown.
4. When serializing numbers, always be sure to use the invariant culture.  `Utf8JsonWriter.WriteNumber()` will do that correctly, but when formatting numbers manually pass `NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo` or `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to your formatting method.
5. It isn't clear from your question whether the `Id` property value should be serialized as a number or a string.  If a string, use

   ```
   writer.WriteString($"users__{x.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)}__id", user.Id.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
   ```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ugg8s3) for a single converter, and #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xos8A3) for two converters.

Comment: I left out a lot of stuff in the examples to make things simpler, but I appreciate the time you dedicated to point various things out.

I did think of writing a converter for the "root" class, but while the request in the example is small, the actual one is a complex object graph, which means a lot of code I would need to write and possibly update/mantain if the API changes, which is probable since it's in active development.

On point 4 "Id" is actually an integer. The example I provided is wrong, apologies.

Comment: @SimoFerrari - In a contract-based serializer such as System.Text.Json a child class cannot control the serialization of a parent class  (or in any other contract-based serializer as far as I know).  It's the responsibility of each class (or its applicable converter) to serialize itself as it sees fit, then any child classes will get serialized according to their respective contracts.

Comment: @SimoFerrari - if you are trying to "flatten" a serialization graph so that child object properties are included as part of some parent object, then I'd suggest asking a new question with a proper [mcve].

Comment: thanks for your help. Much appreciated. 
I ended up using a converter for the request and handle child objects (except the user list which as you correctly understood becomes part of the parent object) using an approach as in your second fiddle.